# How to select value from Dropdown without using Select class, Becuase in have dropdown as listbox in the span not select?

Tags: selenium, select, webdriver, dropdown

```
My HTML code is here:
    <fieldset>
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="qs-formfield-short qs-required">
<label for="stateCountry">State or Province</label>
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="stateCountry_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Please Select...</span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
</span>
</span>
```

My Code is here:

WebElement stateDropDown = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/main/div/div/div/span/div/fieldset/div[4]/div[1]/span/span[1]"));
                List options = stateDropDown.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul/li[44]"));

```
    for(WebElement opt : options){
        if ("Texas".equals(opt.getText()));
        opt.click();
        System.out.println(opt);
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant HTML, starting from a `<form` or at least a `<fieldset`

Comment: I have updated the HTML and start from <fieldset>.  I hope this enough fo you. thanks

Comment: Please explain your problem explicitly. Are you see any result or your outputs are wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);    
WebElement optionsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'k-dropdown-wrap')]"));
action.moveToElement(optionsList);

List<WebElement> options = driver.getElemets(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'k-input')]"));
for(WebElement option : options) {
    if (option.getText().equals("Texas")) {
        option.click();
    }
}
```

Stop writing strange xpath to elements :)

Comment: sorry i am new in automation and learning things. thanks for your advise and help!

Comment: The above solution is incorrect as there is no Web driver method called as getElemets() or getElements()

Comment: So you need just the object of WebDriver class, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to select JDK 1.8 at [this address](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) (JDK dropdown to select java version )

```
//Click on Country Dropdown  
        driver.findElement(By.name("JDK")).click();
        List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='JDK']//option"));
        System.out.println(allOptions.size());                                           
        for(int i = 0; i<=allOptions.size()-1; i++) {
             if(allOptions.get(i).getText().contains("JDK 1.8")) {
                    allOptions.get(i).click();
                break;
```