# Checking if dropdown item is selected

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm having a parametrized test that is filling the text fields with the different passwords plus a fixture that fills other fields that doesn't need to be changed in every test (I have 3 tests for passwords).
The fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fill_create_user_form_except_password(driver):
    users_page = UsersPage(driver)
    users_page.set_name("wow username")
    users_page.set_surname("such surname")
    users_page.choose_company("company name")
    users_page.set_email("smart@email.com")
    users_page.choose_language("English")
    users_page.choose_role("User")
    users_page.choose_random_timezone()
```

The problem I have - is that the first test is going okay, but when the fixture runs for the second time, dropdowns for company, role and language are getting cleared. So the first time you click an item in DD - it is being selected, the second time you click - it is being cleared - this runs the tests because every field must be filled.
The next problem - our dropdowns doesn't have a `Select` tag so I can't import `Select` lib and do stuff with it.
The question - how can I check if the dropdown item is selected and do not select if it already is?
HTML code for the dropdown:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="choose company" class="el-input__inner" style="height: 36px;">
```

-I choose the needed item by using `send_keys("company_name")`

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: sendKeys will not work for dropdowns. May be this will help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848352/how-to-select-value-from-dropdown-without-using-select-class-becuase-in-have-dr

Comment: @Dhamo send_keys() works for our dropdowns - I get the list of dropdown items and then send keys of the item I need. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: Please post the HTML of the dropdown with initial value selected and with a specific (non-default) value selected. I'm assuming the HTML is different... that difference will be the key in determining what is selected.

Comment: @JeffC Default HTML looks like I've already posted in the question, and when I have a company chosen, the only difference in `placeholder="choose company"` becomes `placeholder=""`. Please see the screenshot: https://gyazo.com/f47d150532ef8e3a7cf07e00af505e1f

Comment: So... if you know that, you now have the answer to your question.